# Sort table but not the first and third column

Tags: jquery, sorting

I am using the datatables.net jquery table sorter which sorts all header elements.

My problem is that I am new to jquery and I need only a few headers to be sorted. I need something like: sort all headers but the first and third ones.

I have this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" class="init">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.mytable').dataTable( {
        "scrollCollapse": true,
        "paging":         false
    } );
} );
</script>
```

Comment: Please provide a HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Check [the official documentation](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.orderable), including examples ;)

Something like this for first and third deactivated:

```
$('.mytable').dataTable( {
    "scrollCollapse": true,
    "paging":         false,
    "columns": [
      { "orderable": false },
      null,
      { "orderable": false },
      null,
      ...
    ]
} );
```

Just did it in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3jcgeupg/1/

Comment: you can probably also add `data-ordering="false"` to headers 1 and 3, in your html

Comment: I couldn't get it work. I checked the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#example').dataTable( {
      "aoColumnDefs": [
          { 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [ 0 ] }
       ]
});

} );
```